# getUserMedia() allow user to continue even if permission is denied

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc

My sample getUserMedia() asks for permission for the camera and microphone.

```
let constraints = { audio: true, video: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
    // Do stuff
}).catch(e => alert(`getUserMedia error ${e.name}`))
```

If the user doesn't accept the camera and/or microphone permission request I get an alert error as expected.

Is it possible to still ask for audio and video, but if the user refuses, then their devices won't be used but, would still allow the user to browse the site?

Thank you.

Comment: *and the web page crashes*. That isn't supposed to happen in any case. Are you sure that `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is the culprit?

Comment: Sorry. I just looked at the code and it doesn't crash it just doesn't run the code in // do stuff. It runs only the code in the catch block which means I never get the stream variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to run in either cases, then you'll have to split up and re-arrange your code in a way so that you can run it.

If the user accepts the stream, then go with `doStuffWithStream`, if not then call `doStuffWithoutStream`.

If something needs to happen in both cases, then you could use the [`finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) method to run code in both cases.

```
function doStuffWithStream(stream) {
  // Do stuff with stream.
}

function doStuffWithoutStream() {
  // Do stuff without stream.
}

function doStuffEitherWay() {
  // Do stuff in both cases.
}

let constraints = { audio: true, video: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
  doStuffWithStream(stream);
}).catch(e => {
  alert(`getUserMedia error ${e.name}`);
  doStuffWithoutStream();
}).finally(() => {
  doStuffEitherWay();
});
```